# Draw an external views content into the internal canvas, while dimming it?

Tags: android, canvas, view

I am drawing the contents of another view inside my custom view, like so:

```
@Override
public void draw(final Canvas canvas){
    // Draw lower filler
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.bottom - mStartBounds.bottom);
    canvas.clipRect(0, mStartBounds.bottom, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mOuterView.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    // Draw upper filler
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.top - mStartBounds.top);
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), mStartBounds.top);
    mOuterView.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    // Draw content
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.top);
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, mCurrentExpansionRect.right, mCurrentExpansionRect.height());
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

mOuterView is the view which supplies the background and gets drawn on the top and bottom of my custom view (these backgrounds are called upper and lower "filler")

I want to dim the upper and lower filler, but I cannot modify its paint.

Can I draw the contents of another view inside my custom view while modifying the output, like dimming it?

I want to avoid drawing a dimming layer above the already drawn upper and lower filler to avoid overdraw.

EDIT:
Video of the final result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72g7LQ0vdug
The rows above and below the expanding view are the upper and lower fillers and should get progressively dimmed while the row expands.

Comment: Its really weird looking code, but not illegal.  I'd comment why you're doing it for future maintainers though.

Comment: Drawing another view to your canvas.  For one, it tightly couples this view with the outer view.  Usually something not done in drawing code.  I'd be curious what that view actually was-  if its just an image or background you're probably better off using a Drawable in this class rather than using 2 views to get this effect.  Or possibly merging these two views into one if one/both has real data in it.  Hard to say on that idea though, because I don't totally get what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The use case is very specific. It is for an expanding RecyclerView row without touching the recyclerview. It overlays the new expanding layout and animates a row expansion. To move the rows above and below the expanding row the content of the recyclerview is drawn on the canvas above and below the expanding row. Very similar to the new inbox app by google. I will create a video and add it to this post to show what it is supposed to do, hold on.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have added the video. Once you click a row the recyclerview is overlaid with my custom view and the row expansion is animated. The recyclerview rows above and below the expanding row are the upper and lower filler that gets drawn into the canvas of my expanding custom view and should be dimmed.

Comment: Cool effect.  Yeah, given this very unique use case I can see this being the easiest way.  The only other way I can see it would be to have the new view as part of the recyclerview and then letting the views above and below redraw themselves with a dimmer background.  Either way is going to lead to some code that's a bit complex.  If I saw this in a code review for this reason I wouldn't be in love with it, but I'd be ok with it.  Definitely want it commented.

Comment: One last thought-  a slightly cleaner implementation may be to enable the drawing cache on the view you're covering, and grabbing the content of the view as a bitmap.  That may be a bit less confusing, and even a bit faster if the views are complex.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes! This was my first implementation (grabbing the drawing cache) but when I tested it, I had troubles with it working on some devices and not on others, but I think this stems from me not enabling the drawing cache explicitly, I might try that. The drawbacks of that approach are that the recyclerview rows stop all their animated content (such as progressbars) when they get converted to a bitmap, which might look weird when we add animated content later, so I was trying to avoid that. Now, on to my initial question: Do you know of a way to add a dimming effect on the fillers?

Comment: Regarding your second solution of having the expanding view as part of the recyclerview: This was our first solution but it invited a range of other problems because of how recyclerview is built for efficiency and view recycling. So we tried to find another, simpler approach without touching the recyclerview too much. Additionally the expanded row should contain a viewpager in the end, which would be especially hard to do efficiently if we expand the actual recyclerview rows. This custom view approach seems much simpler and more versatile.

Comment: There's no chance you work for Facebook is there?  You seem to be solving similar problems to the ones I've seen here.  Anyway the one way I know of to dim an image is to draw black behind it and apply an alpha factor.  That should have the effect of making it darker.

Comment: @GabeSechan Haha, no but thank you, I take it as a compliment that you would think that! I am working in a small startup in Germany, but maybe one day haha. I have added a gradient filler now, which produces some overdraw, but I guess we will have to optimize that somehow later. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to draw gradients over the fillers, this produces additional overdraw which I wanted to avoid, but seems to be the only way to do it

```
@Override
public void draw(final Canvas canvas){
    // Draw lower filler
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.bottom - mStartBounds.bottom);
    canvas.clipRect(0, mStartBounds.bottom, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mOuterView.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    // Draw lower filler shadow
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.bottom);
    mFillerShadowPaint.setShader(mLowerFillerShadow);
    mFillerShadowPaint.setAlpha((int) (mAnimatedFraction * 255));
    canvas.drawPaint(mFillerShadowPaint);
    canvas.restore();

    // Draw upper filler
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.top - mStartBounds.top);
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), mStartBounds.top);
    mOuterView.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    // Draw upper filler shadow
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.top - mTopDistance);
    mFillerShadowPaint.setShader(mUpperFillerShadow);
    mFillerShadowPaint.setAlpha((int) (mAnimatedFraction * 255));
    canvas.drawPaint(mFillerShadowPaint);
    canvas.restore();

    // Draw content
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, mCurrentExpansionRect.top);
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, mCurrentExpansionRect.right, mCurrentExpansionRect.height());
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```